# Can you trade items with other players?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

I noticed on the Pause menu that there is an option for "Receive Items":

[image: receive-menu]

When you highlight that option, a message appears at the bottom of the screen:

[image: receive-message]

I can't find any info in the tutorials or tips (that I have so far), and when playing with friends I don't see any relevant options.

Is there a way to send items to other people? Or is this an as-yet unexplained feature that I haven't unlocked yet?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I actually figured this out, you simply have to be in a multiplayer session, go into your item pouch (not the bin), and select an item.

There should be an option to 'Give', although I was unable to give certain items away (Godbugs, specifically). You seem to be able to give items to anyone on your current online session.

Comment: Certain items cannot be given, I haven't figure out the rules of giving in MHW but in past versions only low rarity items can be given.

Comment: In previous versions I believe only items of rarity 1-3 could be given away. Most crafting/gathering materials are rarity 4+.

Comment: I would expect it to be consumable items, such as Potions, Antidotes, and the like.  So if someone forgot Antidotes you could help them out in a pinch.

Comment: I was able to do it with common harvestables too, such as blue mushroom

Comment: I am almost certain that carves (even the lowest rarity ones) have been impossible to give in earlier installments. Basically, anything that could in theory allow a player to get stronger gear than what they themselves have killed.

Comment: Basically, you can't give crafting materials. To prevent people from becoming too powerful without working for it themselves. You have to grind for items you need.

Answer (score 4):

The online [manual](http://game.capcom.com/manual/MHW/en/xone/page/16/6) says, that you can only give items from your item pouch:

> During online multiplayer, you can select items (with some exceptions) from your item pouch to give to other players.

Comment: That is cool to have confirmation, any idea how to do it though?

Answer (score -2):

Go to your item pouch select the item, then hit GIVE select the player and badaboombadading they get the item. Only some consumables and other lower tier items can be given. Monster bits cannot be given